# Fixing a water tap that only comes out with high pressure suddenly

Tags: plumbing

Moved into a new apartment, and the taps in the kitchen have an issue where if you turn the tap multiple times, barely any water comes out (if any), then you get to a point where the water comes out in a big high pressure wave and continues with the high pressure water from there.

To me (a non plumber) this seems like there's some kind of fallthrough where it needs to reach a certain pressure to have water come out, and that fallthroug has been set to a too-high pressure.

Is there anything I can do about this, so the tap works at a lower pressure and doesn't come out suddenly?

Comment: Do you know if your water is supplied by an on-demand pump? The change in pressure from low to high could be caused by the delayed starting of such a pump.

Comment: Is there any way I can tell? Looking at videos of 'on demand pump' taps it seems likely but I don't know if I could tell for sure.

Comment: Does this only happen on one tap/faucet? Would you edit in a picture of the tap, or supply the make/model?